# Excel / How to automatically find the correct option from a drop down list while typing in the cell , for an entire column

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, autofill

I work at a currier company and daily data inputs are numerous. I made a table and in a column I made every cell a drop down list , each new data entry creates a new row and that specific column cell becomes a drop down list for the input. It takes source data from a different tab from the file. The source data for my drop down list is massive , more than 100 rows, so my only option was to click the cell, scroll down the bar to find my choice from the list based on alphabetical order...I am looking for a better solution where I can just type in the cell and show me underneath the possible choices from the list, in a similar manner to the  excel filter search bar. Basicly to be more specific, for each input row I create, I need to register a location and that location cell is my drop down list. I have more than 200 locations therefore I need a way to fine my right choice as I type in the cell . Some locations may be similar so I need to view similar choices.

Is this possible and if so how?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-h2UER3b_0&t=103s) from Leila

Comment: At first I though it was a single viewing text box she used but now I think that with some changes I may be able to implement it in my file... Thanks this helped.